# Android - Recyclerview/arraylist with multiple objects?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm wondering how I can implement multiple objects in my recyclerview fed by my arraylist. I don't particularly want to change a lot of code. Here is what I have currently:
Viewholder:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

TextView exercise;
TextView percent;
TextView reps;
TextView weight;
CheckBox check1;
CardView mCardView;
ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    exercise= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtExercise);
    percent= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
    reps= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtReps);
    weight= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtWeight);
    check1 = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.check1);
    mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

}
}
```

Rv fed by arraylist:

```
 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("checkState", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//RECYCLERVIEW
    final RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerFri);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

    rv.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(this.getActivity(), getFriWorkout(), 3));

private ArrayList<Workout> getFriWorkout() {
    ArrayList<Workout> workout = new ArrayList<>();
    switch (workout3) {
        case "w29": {
            Workout workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "50", "5", bench50, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "60", "5", bench60, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "70", "4", bench70, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "75", "3", bench75, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "75", "3", bench75, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "80", "2", bench80, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "80", "2", bench80, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "75", "3", bench75, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "75", "3", bench75, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "70", "4", bench70, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "60", "6", bench60, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.benchpress), "50", "8", bench50, false);
            workout.add(workouts);

            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.db_fly), "5 Sets", "10 Reps", "", false);
            workout.add(workouts);

            workouts = new Workout(getActivity().getString(R.string.squat), "50", "5", squat50, false);
            workout.add(workouts);
```

RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<Workout> workout;
SharedPreferences prefs;
int firstSecondOrThird;
int colorResId = R.color.defaultcard;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Workout> workout, int thePosition) {
    mContext = context;
    this.workout = workout;
    this.firstSecondOrThird = thePosition;
}
// INITIALIZE HOLDER
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.workout_item, null);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

private SparseBooleanArray mCheckedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();

//BIND DATA TO VIEWS
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.exercise.setText(workout.get(position).getExercise());
    holder.percent.setText(workout.get(position).getPercent());
    holder.reps.setText(workout.get(position).getReps());
    holder.weight.setText(workout.get(position).getWeight());
    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    holder.check1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            prefs.edit().putBoolean(firstSecondOrThird + "checkState" + position, isChecked).apply();
        }
    });
    holder.check1.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(firstSecondOrThird+"checkState"+position, false));
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return workout.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}
```

Basically what I want to do is add a second layout to inflate underneath certain exercises that only have 5 checkboxes.. I have read a few other answers, but found them quite confusing as I'm new to android.. I'm wondering if theres an easy way without changing a lot of code, as I have a ton of data to do this for. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You are somewhat on the right track. Within your MyRecyclerAdapter, you will need to override the onCreateViewHolder() method to inflate your custom layout and supply it to your ViewHolder. Here is a link to a project I worked on sometime back which shows how you can do this (https://github.com/ucsunil/Lockers/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ebay/lockers/adapters/HomePageItemsAdapter.java). I used an ArrayList to supply data to the ViewHolder as well.

Your individual rows need to be bound to the ViewHolder using the onBindViewHolder() method.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add my adapter class, I am already doing that and it is working good. The problem I'm having is I'm not sure how to add a second and third custom layout to my recycler and viewholder.